# is AOT + JIT supported in ivy?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5

I have a requirement to create compiled template at run time in my angular project.

let me explain the scenario,

I get template from my database, which is something like

```
const template = '<span>{{data}}</span>';
```

And In my component i get this data and do innerHTML on div like below;

```
<div [innerHTML]="template"></div>
```

but interpolation not working.

I have overcome this issue with ngx-dynamic (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dynamic). But by using this, i can't able to do AoT compilation.

I want to make this possible with AoT compiled angular app, which work alongside with jit.

Is it possible with ivy? Please advice what to do.

Comment: can u please update, if you have found the answer to it